# Visual Studio can't find Nuget packages from private Nuget Server

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-server

I am running NuGet.Server v2.8.60717.93, hosted on Azure. The server is running correctly, and I am able to see all the packages if I go to the following url:

```
https://***.azurewebsites.net/nuget/Packages
```

I am also able to publish new packages to the server using Nuget Package Explorer.

I added `https://***.azurewebsites.net/nuget` as a Package Source in Visual Studio. However it can't find any packages, it just says `No items found`.

To my understanding, Nuget will set /Packages as default package folder unless otherwise is specified. I even tried to set `packagesPath` to `~/Packages`, still no luck.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Also have this problem the RSS feed of package is showing in the browser if I navigate to https://***.azurewebsites.net/nuget/Packages but no items found in visual studio.